# Olympus T2 Adapter ring stuck on my Sony Alpha — how can I get it unstuck?

Tags: lens, lens-mount, lens-adapter

Edited.
I bought a Samyang 500mm Mirror lens off ebay so that i could try and expirement with tele photos before i decided to buy really expensive lenses..

I got the lens with a T2 Adapter (Olympus) Written on it [Edit-This ring is about 3mm to small for the Sony Alpha and the flanges are shorter- so it slips past the locking mechanism and 'gets stuck' in the void..]

[image]

which i screwed on to this side of the Lens [Edit- Cheaper than other.. but a bit of practice and get nice photos.. for the price ;) ]

[image]
[Edit - I was doomed from the start.. The auction is misleading in its words and meant you can buy an adapter but they make it sound as if one fits all- or the correct one is included- buts its not.fine print]

As usual I aligned the red dot the the Alphas red dot- put it in and screwed clockwise.. a bit unusual at first as it rotated about 1/4 around.. and my other lenses only twist and lock quickly..

I did not make anything off it and started experimenting and taking photos all looks OK.

Then when i try to unlock the lens anti-clock wise.. I realised there is play- that its not actually locked in properly... and there is about 1/2cm play either way on rotation and I cannot remove the adapter :( The actual lens screws of the apter ring but the ring stays in :( I press the release button and nothing- it wont turn any further.. I tried slight force and nothing. wiggling it up down-.. it stuck - but loose.

Can anybody advise how to remove the damn ring.. is there a a release inside the barrel somewhere? can i unscrew something to get to the mechanism.. I know the mirror need to be untouched and work in a dust free environment.

Surely i am not the only plonker that has done this.. I actually ordered the correct  adpater now.. but the original sale description says this

> -T2 adapter ( allowed you to used it on other brand camera) 
>   SAMYANG 500mm MC
>
> f/8.0 Mirror Lens works with following
>   cameras:
>   - Canon EOS 5D, 50D, 40D, 30D, 20D, 10D, 450D, 400D, 350D, 300D, 1000D, 7D
>   - Nikon D3X, D700, D300, D200, D100, D90, D80, D70, D70s, D60, D50, D40,
>   D40X, D3000, D5000
>   - Sony Alpha A900 A850 A700 A550 A500 A380 A350 A300 A230 A230 A200 A100
>   - Olympus E-30, E-3, E-520, E-510, E-500, E-420, E-410, E-400, E-330,
>   E-300
>   - Pentax K20D, K10D, K200D, K110D, K100D, K100D Super, K-m   AND MANY
>   MORES

[Some thing similar happened to this guy- dont know what he did in the end](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/pentax-slr-lens-discussion/65110-t-mount-adaptor-stuck-my-k20d-not-next-week.html)

and even the guy selling it said it will fit straight in... I am so annoyed.. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the link you posted the Pentax forum, the guy mounted the lens back on the camera for extra grip and slowly applied force and it eventually came off - so there's that option...**but**...

The safest option is going to be to take it to local place or send your camera in to have it removed.  If you damage the mount while trying remove it yourself through force you could end up spending quite a bit of money.

Comment: I finally got the courage to open the camera today- unscrewed all the plastic things and realsied that i would have to rip the guts out to get the the ring to be able to somehow release the unwanted adapter.. no way hose!  I wiggled the apater up down- on the opposite side a bit here bit there.. little force.. out it came.. piece of $**t :(  It is literally 3mm to small and the locking nut and groove do not align.. ordered the proper one a few days ago...

Comment: @ppumkin - glad you got it out! When you get the chance post some pics with that mirror lens in chat, I've been looking at them and would appreciate it.